# How to overlay a widget in Flutter with another widget, opacity set to multiply?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

This is what I want to achieve:

[image: Goal]

I know that there's a colorBlendMode on the image widget, but it doesn't allow me to color a part of the image, just the whole. Is it possible to overlay color for a percentage of the image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For color overlay, you could simply use Container with color that has opacity. Then if you put your image and Container in Stack you could get same result as you have.

EDIT: 
If you want to use multiply blending only option that comes to my mind is take two picture one with colorFiler, second(cutted in half) without and put them together. But it's definitely not clean or somehow nice solution.

Code for similar result as your image:

```
Column(children: <Widget>[
        Stack(children: <Widget>[
          Image(
              image: NetworkImage('https://picsum.photos/600?image=9'),
              colorBlendMode: BlendMode.multiply,
              color: Colors.green),
          AspectRatio(
              aspectRatio: 2 / 1,
              child: new Container(
                  decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                      image: new DecorationImage(
                          fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
                          alignment: FractionalOffset.topCenter,
                          image: NetworkImage(
                            'https://picsum.photos/600?image=9',
                          ))))),
        ]),
        Stack(children: <Widget>[
          Image(
              image: NetworkImage(
                  'https://www.solidbackgrounds.com/images/1920x1080/1920x1080-white-solid-color-background.jpg'),
              height: 100,
              fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              colorBlendMode: BlendMode.multiply,
              color: Colors.green),
          Center(
              child: Text('5',
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 40)))
        ])
      ])
```

Comment: Yes, sry for being unclear. Heres an illustrative example: [illustration](https://imgur.com/a/xiLgkp8) . On the left is the solution you propose, but the one I wish to implement is on the right. I want to have an overlay with color blending set to multiply.

Answer (score 1):

I would definitely consider looking into the [Stack](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html) Widget, which allows you to overlay children on top of one another. You could have your base image on the bottom, and that filter just above it.

Comment: What widget would you overlay the image with? I haven't found a widget that would allow a color filter.

Comment: That I'm not too sure :( I figure you can make a white image just above the main one which is nearly transparent, and then add a multiply color blend to it